# Finding left and right limits at the discontinuities of $y =\frac{ x^3+3x^2-10x}{x^2-25}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

> Find the left and right limits at all points where the function is discontinuous and determine the
> type of discontinuity: $$y =\frac{
> x^3+3x^2-10x}{x^2-25}$$

**My try:**

> I start with trying to find the limits using the graph, but how do you do it algebraically, can anyone give me some pointers. $x$ cannot be equal to either $5$ or $-5$.

Comment: Please make your subject line informative about the mathematical content of your post, rather than about you.

Comment: What kind of functions is the fraction made of, and what do you know about their continuity?

Comment: what would the left and right limit be though?

Comment: @neverlandusers20061 Ask yourself: where can the function be discontinuous?

Answer (score 0):

Let $y = f(x)$.

We can try factoring.
\begin{gather*}\frac{x^{3} + 3x^{2} - 10x}{x^{2} - 25} \\ \frac{x(x^{2} + 3x - 10)}{(x - 5)(x + 5)} \\ \frac{x(x + 5)(x - 2)}{(x + 5)(x - 5)}\end{gather*}

We can see that $x + 5$ exists in both numerator and denominator. We can conclude that $x = -5$ is a point discontinuity.

Also, we can see that $x - 5$ is the remaining term in the denominator. We know that it must never be zero. Setting this to zero, \begin{align*}x - 5 &= 0 \\ x &= 5\end{align*}

We can see that $x = 5$ makes it zero, hence $x = 5$ is an infinite/essential discontinuity.

---

Edit:

To prove that $x = -5$ is a point discontinuity, we solve for the limit of $f$ as $x$ approaches $-5$.
\begin{align*}\lim_{x \to -5}f(x) &= \frac{x^{3} + 3x^{2} - 10x}{x^{2} - 25} \\ 
\lim_{x \to -5}f(x) &= \frac{x(x + 5)(x - 2)}{(x + 5)(x - 5)} \\ \lim_{x \to -5}f(x) &= \frac{x(x - 2)}{(x - 5)} \\ \lim_{x \to -5}f(x) &= \frac{\lim_{x \to -5}\left[x(x - 2)\right]}{\lim_{x \to -5}\left[x - 5\right]} \\ \lim_{x \to -5}f(x) &= \frac{-5(-5 - 2)}{(-5 - 5)} \\ \lim_{x \to -5}f(x) &= -\frac{7}{2}\end{align*}

The limit is shown to be $-\frac{7}{2}$. This means that both left hand limit and right hand limit are $-\frac{7}{2}$.

Because the limit exists but the function at that point does not, therefore, $x = -5$ is a point discontinuity.

We now try to prove that $x = 5$ is an infinite/essential discontinuity. Because we know that $x - 5$ is a term in the denominator and in the denominator alone, $x = 5$ must be a vertical asymptote. Solving for the limit of $f$ as $x$ approaches $5$ from the left, let $x = 5 - \delta$, for $\delta \geq 0$. Rewriting and solving for the limit,
\begin{align*}\lim_{\delta \to 0}f(x) &= \frac{(5 - \delta)(5 - \delta - 2)}{5 - \delta - 5} \\ &= \frac{(5 - \delta)(3 - \delta)}{-\delta}\end{align*}

As $\delta$ approaches zero, $\lim f(x)$ approaches $-\infty.$

Solving for the right hand limit of $f$ as $x$ approaches $5$ from the right, let $x = 5 + \delta$, for $\delta \geq 0$. Rewriting and solving for the limit,
\begin{align*}\lim_{x \to 5^{+}}f(x) &= \frac{x(x - 2)}{(x - 5)} &= \frac{(5 + \delta)(5 + \delta - 2)}{(5 + \delta - 5)} \\ &= \frac{(5 + \delta)(3 + \delta)}{\delta}\end{align*}

As $\delta$ approaches zero, $\lim f(x)$ approaches $+\infty.$

Because the one-sided limits increases/decreases without bound, we can conclude that $x = 5$ is an infinite/essential discontinuity.

Comment: But the question asks for the left and right limits

Comment: And $f(5)$ makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Sorry, will revise. The $f(5)$ is just a habit that needs to be stopped.

Answer (score 0):

So there are four limits to consider, as $x$ approaches $5,-5$ from the left and the right.  I'll do two, leave the rest for you.  Note that the numerator equals $x(x+5)(x-2)$.  Thus as $x\to5^+$, we can cancel, and just get $\dfrac{x(x-2)}{x-5}\to\infty$. The limit coming in from the left is $-\infty$. (The limit as $x$ approaches $-5$ is just $-7/2$, for similiar reasons.)

So the discontinuity at $5$ is not removable, the one at $-5$ is.